# Powershell: Build multiple level PSObject to output for JSON

Tags: powershell

I have a PS1 that gathers multiple bits of information about a computer. Several steps loop through an array and I need to add elements to a `PSObject`. This failing for each attempt (create new `PSObject` and add to `PSObject`; create a multidimensional array and add to `PSObject`; attempt to build hash and add to `PSObject`).

I'm getting `$drives`

```
$drives = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 4}
```

And the resultant `PSObject | ConvertTo-JSON` should be

```
 {
   "metrics":{
     "run": worksfine
     "cpu": worksfine
     "memory": worksfine
   },
   "disks":[
     {
       "drive": I_have_Info; CannotPopulateCorrectly,
       "freeSpace": I_have_Info; CannotPopulateCorrectly
     },
     {
       "drive": I_have_Info; CannotPopulateCorrectly,
       "freeSpace" I_have_Info; CannotPopulateCorrectly
     }
   ]
 }
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
cls
$output = New-Object PSObject

### METRICS ###
$metrics = New-Object PSObject
# Current time date
$lastRun = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy"
$metrics | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty lastRun $lastRun

# Get Avg CPU
$cpu = (gwmi win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average
$metrics | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty cpu $cpu

# Get Available Memory
$memory = (Get-Counter -counter "\Memory\Available MBytes").CounterSamples | Select-Object -expandProperty CookedValue

# Get Total Memory
$totalMem = ((gwmi CIM_PhysicalMemory).Capacity)[0] / 1048576

# Percent free Memory
$freeMemory = [math]::round($memory / $totalMem, 2) * 100
$metrics | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty memory $freeMemory

$output | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty metrics $metrics
### END METRICS ###
### DISKS ###
# Get Disk Drives
$drives = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
$disks = ## What should this be? ##
foreach($drive in $drives)
{
    $id = $drive.DeviceID
    $size = [math]::round($drive.Size / 1073741824, 2)
    $free = [math]::round($drive.FreeSpace  / 1073741824, 2)
    $pct = [math]::round($free / $size, 2) * 100 #SHOW IN JSON
    $disks ## Add drive = $id, freeSpace = $pct - How? ##

## Not able to build a correct element here to add for JSON ##
}
$output | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty disks ##??$disks??#
### END DISKS ###
```

Comment: can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: We need the rest of your code to see whats happening here. For comparison, when I run GWMI win32_LogicalDisk | Convertto-Json, I get perfectly valid output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this could work

```
$info = [pscustomobject]@{
    metrics = [pscustomobject]@{
        run = 'worksfine'
        cpu = 'worksfine'
        memory = 'worksfine'
    }
}

$drives = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 4} | select @{n='drive';e={$_.deviceid}}, freespace

$info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name disks -Value $drives

$info | ConvertTo-Json
```

output

```
{
    "metrics":  {
                    "run":  "worksfine",
                    "cpu":  "worksfine",
                    "memory":  "worksfine"
                },
    "disks":  [
                  {
                      "drive":  "C:",
                      "freespace":  18163093504
                  },
                  {
                      "drive":  "D:",
                      "freespace":  57510354944
                  }
              ]
}
```

Comment: So the initial object must be a pscustomobject, not a 'standard' PSObject?

Comment: no, a standard psobject is fine, but when using the type accelerator you use `[pscustomobject]` and when using `new-object` you do this `new-object psobject -properties @{...}`

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of pscustomobject largely unrequired. Not sure if this only available in later versions of powershell, but this syntax works fine.

```
$driveinfo = @{
   "metrics"= @{
     "run" = "worksfine"
     "cpu" = "worksfine"
     "memory" = "worksfine"
   }   
   "disks" = @(
     @{
       "drive" = "c"
       "freeSpace" = 12442
     }
     @{
       "drive" = "d"
       "freeSpace"  = 3214124
     }
   )
}

$driveinfo | ConvertTo-JSON
```